# Identical Queries To Find Data Folder

Tags: sql-database, performance

After an upgrade to 10.3 we started to see identical SQL queries, which put a lot of stress on the SQL server. The query:

```
exec sp_executesql N' SELECT [ID] FROM [Items] WHERE [ParentID] = @parentId AND [Name] = @childName',
N'@parentId uniqueidentifier,@childName nvarchar(4)',
@parentId='DB47C573-0E0A-4C5F-A264-DB8584B23DD7',@childName=N'data'
```

We see as many queries as there are components on our page. The data sources are referenced locally, e.g.:

local:/Data/HeaderModuleDatasource

local:/Data/DetailsModuleDatasource

local:/Data/HostModuleDatasource

local:/Data/EssayModuleDatasource

local:/Data/RelatedArticlesModuleDatasource

local:/Data/BackgroundImageDatasource

local:/Data/CarouselModuleDatasource

In this case, we are seeing 7 identical SQL requests per page. Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: My guess is that you have a problem with your cache. I would only expect 1 hit to the `./data` folder on an uncached page. XM/XP will get the data folder for each of those queries, but the first request for it, _should_ add the data folder to the data or item caches and prevent the other SQL queries from being called. Can you check that your caches are enabled and not out of space?